# python2.7 pyqt4 non latin characters

Tags: python, encoding, console, pyqt4

I m' developing a python2.7 qt4 application that fetches non-latin characters from a mysql database and prints them to the console. I am using pydev and eclipse. The application runs fine when i run it from the eclipse IDE but when i run my app from the console it does not  behave as it should. Any ideas why this might be happening? I am using an arch linux machine.

Comment: This is possibly because the default encoding of your console is not suitable.

Comment: However, your question is too vague and we need more details about the output and expected output. How do you get help when all we know is "does not behave as it should"?

Comment: I have a textEdit widget and a listwidget in my form.When i type something in the textEdit widget the listwidget gets populated with the distinct characters of the textEdit. Those characters are also printed in the console. When i type non-latin characters in the textEdit widget the console and the listwidget output question marks instead of the actual characters.  I have also another listwidget item that displays the non-latin characters stored in the database. This widget does n't display anything. That is the problem. I can't see the non-latin characters when i run my app from the terminal

Answer (score 0):

This might be because the default encoding of your terminal does not support UTF-8 characters.

[Here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Configuring_locales) is a link that describes how to change the default encoding of your terminal.

Here is a summary of what it describes:

1. Uncomment a UTF-8 locale in `/etc/locale.gen`, e.g. `en_US.UTF-8 UTF-8`
2. Run `locale-gen` as root.

To make the locale changes system-wide:

1. add `LANG="en_US.UTF-8"` to `/etc/locale.conf`

You may have to restart your terminal after the changes.